# Formatting Angular JS/Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Javascript/Html/Angular newbie here. Run into a problem that has me stumped, can't find anything online to help me.

I've created a small application that uses Bootstrap tabs. Here's the code responsible for creating the tabs:

```
<tabset class="tab-container">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active"> <!-- the tab highlight directive -->
      <tab-heading>
      <span>{{tab.title}}</span>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="removeTab($event, $index)"></i> <!-- the tab close button -->
    </tab-heading>
    {{tab.content}}
  </tab>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addTab()"></button>
</tabset>
```

I want to add highlights to certain words in the tabs (for example, if the tab contents were "the lazy fox", I would want to highlight just fox in yellow). When I try adding html tags to tab.content, the tabs don't parse the html tags and simply displays them as normal text.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, that you are using AngularUI (which is great :) ). So here is filter to solve your problem:

1. **Add Javascript** to your project (you can reuse it everywhere):

   https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular-sanitize.js

and

```
angular.module('highlightDemo', ['ngSanitize']);
```

and the following filter:

```
app.filter('highlight', function () {
    return function (text, search, caseSensitive) {
        if (text && (search || angular.isNumber(search))) {
            text = text.toString();
            search = search.toString();
            if (caseSensitive) {
                return text.split(search).join('<span class="ui-match">' + search + '</span>');
            } else {
                return text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), '<span class="ui-match">$&</span>');
            }
        } else {
            return text;
        }
    };
});
```

2. **Setup the highlight options** (in your controller):

   $scope.hightlightSearchKeyword = 'the fox';

And now we are able to use the filter everywhere.

```
<span ng-bind-html="tab.content | highlight:hightlightSearchKeyword"></span>
```

3. Make sure you add add **a CSS style** for span.ui-match for example

   .ui-match {
      background: yellow;
    }

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, but I'm a bit slow :P I'm still not quite sure where to put the <span ng-bind...> filter in order to modify the tab content. I tried:   $scope.tabs.push({ title: 'Tab ' + counter, content: compiled});   (with the compiled variable being <span ng-bind...>, but it still displays the html tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML tags within an AngularJS output, you have to use ng-bind-html to output them safely:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

```
<ANY
  ng-bind-html="expression">
...
</ANY>
```

Comment: Don't forget to include ngSanitize if you use this.